# Assigning to property with 'readonly' atribute not allowed

Tags: objective-c, xcode, properties, aqgridview

I' doing the implementation of AQGridView, and everything was going well.

But, now I'm getting the error below.

```
- (AQGridViewCell *) gridView: (AQGridView *)inGridView cellForItemAtIndex: (NSUInteger) index;
  {
MagazineCell *cell = (MagazineCell *)[inGridView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [MagazineCell cell];
    cell.reuseIdentifier = @"cell";
            //Assigning to property with 'readonly' atribute not allowed
}
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
cell.selectionStyle = AQGridViewCellSelectionStyleGlow;


cell.edicaoLabel.text = [[edicoesArray objectAtIndex:index] name];
    cell.dataLabel.text = [[edicoesArray objectAtIndex:index] name];

return cell;
}
```

I tried to do this on head file

```
@property(nonatomic, readwrite) NSString * reuseIdentifier;
```

I also tried

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSString * reuseIdentifier;
```

But still no work.

I downloaded de example of project 'Actors for Netflix' https://github.com/adrianco/Actors-for-Netflix-on-iPad/

And this code have the same problem when I try to build, and the pre-processor also see it.

This example dont declare the property on header of class file, I tried it on my project as an attempt to fix the problem.

Someone can see the what is the problem?

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The code is designed to be readonly as seen inside of the [AQGridViewCell](https://github.com/matej/AQGridView/blob/master/Classes/AQGridViewCell.h) which the ActorCell inherits from. Just because it is on GitHub does not mean that it works. The reuseIdentifier should be passed into the initializer for `UITableViewCell`s. Here is an example.

```
//MagazineCellCode
+(MagazineCell*)cellWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString*)identifier
{
    MagazineCell *cell = [[[MagazineCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
    //Any custom configuration here
    return cell;
}

//TableView Code
if (!cell) {
    cell = [MagazineCell cellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `@property(nonatomic, retain)` but I'm not 100% certain.  I think both of what you have should be working - have you tried a clean and remake?  What version of Xcode?